# How to update the state for a custom component in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-admin

I have the following scenario: using react-admin infrastructure, for a Resource, I have the following Edit View :

```
import Editor from "react-simple-code-editor";

export const CodeQuestionEdit = props => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <LongTextInput source="text" />
      <TextField label="Code Block" />
      <FormDataConsumer>
        {({ formData }) => (
          <Editor
            value={formData.codeBlock}
            onValueChange={code => {
              //Update the current edit form ....
            }}
            highlight={code =>
              highlight(code, languages.cs)
                .split("\n")
                .map(
                  line =>
                    `<span class="container_editor_line_number">${line}</span>`
                )
                .join("\n")
            }
            padding={10}
            className="container__editor"
          />
        )}
      </FormDataConsumer>
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

Editor component is not part of the react-admin, how can I update the state of the Editor with what the user types? and then pass this value back to the higher component, so when I save, I expect to have the last value typed passed in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the value of user input to state and work with it later, you can use `onChange` attribute.

A simple example you can implement for your component may look like this:

First you need a method that will save the value from input to state.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
   this.setState({ yourState: event.target.value });
};
```

Then you need to just set the `onChange` attribute to your input.

And since your component is wrapped in `react-admin Edit`, the saving process should be secure.

Comment: Hi, I want to display the value on the editor as soon as this is being changed, the ideea is that I dont know how to pass this value from Editor to FormDataConsumer ... or even higher ...

Comment: If you want to display the value of input dynamically you can set a TextField and set its source to state from the example. Also I am not entirely sure what are you using FormDataConsumer for exactly since its made to hide fileds or inpit based on other fields or inputs.